# Visual Studio Code - debug by "Attach" does not work on Mac OS

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug my node js project on Mac. It works very well in "Launch" mode but not in "Attach" mode. In "Attach" mode, when I start debugging, I see VS Code first trying to start the debugger in seconds and then stop suddenly without showing any error message. I leave everything in their default values {"name": "Attached", "type": "node", "address": "localhost", "port":3000}, and I'm sure I'm running the site at http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the answer from MS Support Team, it works like a champ now :) Love VSCode and the team so much.

Below is the answer from Andre Weinand of VSCode Team:

In "Attach" mode the VSCode debugger needs to connect to the debug port of the node runtime, which by default uses the port 5858.
The debugger can not work with "a site" that your node program is servicing.

So can you please make sure that you are launching your node program with the correct debugging arguments, e.g.
node --debug-brk program.js
or
node --debug-brk=3000 program.js

The first uses the default port 5858 and you would have to modify the Attach launch config accordingly.
The second changes the port to 3000 which should work with your Attach launch config.

Comment: To go back to your original question, how do we debug client-side JavaScript of the site served out from http://localhost:3000?

Comment: I even haven't tried debug the client side JavaScript so I can't reply your question :)